# Sampling from a discrete distribution while accounting for past occurrences

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a discrete distribution that I need to sample from. It is heavily skewed and an example is as follows

```
a - 1-40
b - 40-80
c - 80-85
d - 85-90
e - 90-95
f - 95-100
```

To currently sample from this distribution, I'm choosing a random number in the interval `[1,100]` and choosing the corresponding value.

However, I'd like to be certain that if I see one of `[c,d,e,f]` I don't see the exact same value being sampled for the next x samples. The context being that they are powerups in a game I'm building. I'd like the powerups to be random, but not hand out the same powerup to the player repeatedly.

Is there any method that incorporates past occurrences of samples into generating a value or do I have to repeatedly sample till I get a value I'd prefer?

Comment: Repeatedly sampling til you get one that differs is simple and will be effective as long as the success probability isn't very small (which is true in your example, it will always be at least 80%).  This means you only need to do 1/.8 = 1.25 samples before you get a restricted item on average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to shuffle an array containing the values 1-100 and then iterate through as necessary.

For example, an implementation of this in Java:

```
public class PowerUpSelector
{
    private int current;
    private int x;
    private int[] distribution;

    public PowerUpSelector(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
        current = 0;
        distribution = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++)
            distribution[i] = i;

        shuffle(distribution[i]); //implement fisher-yates shuffle here.
    }

    public int returnPowerUpID()
    { 
        if (current >= x)
        {
            shuffle(distribution);
            current = 0;
        }

        return distribution[current++];
    }
```

}

Comment: "Implement shuffle as you like" tends to lead to incorrect implementations. The standard shuffle is [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: This is very interesting. Thanks! What is `x` though?

Comment: You said that you didn't want to sample the same value over x iterations. Thus, after x power up id returns, the distribution is reshuffled and you start from the beginning.

Comment: This has the added benefit of meaning that, in your game, the order in which power ups appear changes after x power ups.